# Position of buttons as3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, position

I need some help with Positions of buttons in AS3. Same as before Topic, i made a IRC client with AS3, but when a user join a channel, there will be a button added, but if there is already a button and the user join new channel on IRC, there will be added new button also, this for every channel that a user does join, but It should to be positioned after the last button (side by side). Same for if a user join more channels. How can i do this on best way with x and y positions?

This is my code for now:

```
function onChannelButton(channel)
{
var test:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var btn:Button;

for(var j:int = 0; j < btn.length; j++) {
    btn = new Button();
    btn.name = "btn";
    btn.label = channel;
    btn.width = 90;
    btn.x = 120;
    btn.y = 487.25;
    test.addChild(btn);
    }
    addChild(test);
}
```

Hopefully, u can help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const PADDING:uint = 10;
const NUM_BUTTONS:uint = 10;

onChannelButton();

function onChannelButton():void {
    var test:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var btn:Button;

    //NUM_BUTTONS or btn.length ? (Don't know about your Button class
    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++) 
    {
            btn = new Button();
            btn.name = "btn";
            btn.width = 90;
            btn.x = (btn.width + PADDING) * i;
            test.addChild(btn);
    }

    addChild(test);
}
```

Comment: gPeart Thanks for your help, but i get 10 buttons, see: http://i42.tinypic.com/w174p1.png - The meaning is if i type '/join #test', there must be a button added, but if i join one more channel, then there must be new button added also to switch between channels, but second channel that i did joined and the second button must be positioned after first button (first channel that i did joined), example: http://i42.tinypic.com/j5cl0i.png

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps me on right way to try with it every time and it is alright now. Only, i must get Parent child's + new function to set button positions.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do something like the following, using your iterator `j` to determine the x and y position.

I've created four variables to hopefully make the code pretty self explanatory. In this case, the y position does not change per btn, which is why the btnSpacingY is set to 0.

```
var btnStartX:Number = 120;
var btnStartY:Number = 487.25;
var btnSpacingX:Number = 120;
var btnSpacingY:Number = 0;

function onChannelButton(channel) {
    var test:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var btn:Button;

    for (var j:int = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        btn = new Button();
        btn.name = "btn";
        btn.label = channel;
        btn.width = 90;
        btn.x = btnStartX + (j * btnSpacingX);
        btn.y = btnStartY + (j * btnSpacingY);
        test.addChild(btn);
    }
    addChild(test);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! But 'length" is the problem in this, because i get this: "Scene 1, Layer 'Main', Frame 3, Line 689 1119: Access of possibly undefined property length through a reference with static type fl.controls:Button.
" and fl.controls.Button is added, whats wrong in this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was just focusing on the part of your question you were asking about. You need to fix the for loop. Change 'btn.length' to the number of buttons you are wanting to create. (e.g., j < 10)